# How to group by week in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a database table `commits` with the following columns:

> id | author_name | author_email | author_date (timestamp) |
>   total_lines

Sample contents are:

```
1 | abc | abc@xyz.com | 2013-03-24 15:32:49 | 1234
2 | abc | abc@xyz.com | 2013-03-27 15:32:49 | 534
3 | abc | abc@xyz.com | 2014-05-24 15:32:49 | 2344
4 | abc | abc@xyz.com | 2014-05-28 15:32:49 | 7623
```

I want to get a result as follows:

```
id | name | week | commits
1  | abc  | 1    | 2
2  | abc  | 2    | 0
```

I searched online for similar solutions but couldnt get any helpful ones.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT      date_part('week', author_date::date) AS weekly,
        COUNT(author_email)           
FROM        commits
GROUP BY    weekly
ORDER BY weekly
```

But its not the right result.

Comment: How is it incorrect?  What is the problem?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

If you have multiple years, you should take the year into account as well.  One way is:

```
SELECT date_part('year', author_date::date) as year,
       date_part('week', author_date::date) AS weekly,
       COUNT(author_email)           
FROM commits
GROUP BY year, weekly
ORDER BY year, weekly;
```

A more natural way to write this uses `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', author_date::date) AS weekly,
       COUNT(author_email)           
FROM commits
GROUP BY weekly
ORDER BY weekly;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff : How can we include zero commit weeks also in this query? I tested this one and it gives all rows with at least one commit.

Comment: @JilsonThomas . . . If you have a question, it is better to ask as a question rather than in a comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Grouping by `date_part('year', x), date_part('week', x)` is most likely not what the user wants and should be considered incorrect. For example the first day of 2017 is still part of week 52 that started in 2016 and therefore the `(2017, 52)` pair is probably not at all what you want as it sorts to the end of 2017. Using ´date_trunc('week', x)` on the other hand works as one would expect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am getting this error - django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function date_trunc(unknown, unknown) is not unique and HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I am using Django and PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Chopra . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a question  with sample data, desired results, an appropriate explanation and database tag, not in a comment.

Comment: Note: `date_part` formats the week as week number (probably more desirable), whereas `date_trunc` gives a date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I would suggest the column name `first_day_of_the_week` instead of `weekly` for `date_trunc('week', author_date::date)`

Answer (score 26):

If you want the count of all the **intermediate weeks** as well where there are **no commits/records**, you can get it by providing a `start_date` and `end_date` to `generate_series()` function

```sql
SELECT t1.year_week week, 
       t2.commit_count 
FROM   (SELECT week, 
               To_char(week, 'IYYY-IW') year_week 
        FROM   generate_series('2020-02-01 06:06:51.25+00'::DATE, 
               '2020-04-05 12:12:33.25+00':: 
               DATE, '1 week'::interval) AS week) t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT To_char(author_date, 'IYYY-IW') year_week, 
                               COUNT(author_email)             commit_count 
                        FROM   commits 
                        GROUP  BY year_week) t2 
                    ON t1.year_week = t2.year_week;
```

The output will be:

```
     week | commit_count  
----------+-------------
2020-05   | 2
2020-06   | NULL  
2020-07   | 1
```

Comment: Worth noting you can `COALESCE(commit_count,0)`, which usually presents the analysis more cleanly and makes numeric calculations easier