# PostgreSQL - Getting consistent year week pairs across years

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, postgresql-10

I've been banging my head towards a solution to retrieving a consistent (year, week) pair in PostrgeSQL.

After looking at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36024712/1979665), and, in particular, at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024712/how-to-group-by-week-in-postgresql/36024734#comment74518640_36024734):

> Grouping by date_part('year', x), date_part('week', x) is most likely
> not what the user wants and should be considered incorrect. For
> example the first day of 2017 is still part of week 52 that started in
> 2016 and therefore the (2017, 52) pair is probably not at all what you
> want as it sorts to the end of 2017. Using ´date_trunc('week', x)` on
> the other hand works as one would expect.

I tried some combination of `date_trunc` and `date_part`. However, none seem to give consistent results.

For instance: consider these two dates between different years: `'2017-01-01'` and `'2020-01-01'`.

I think the correct (year, week) pair for them should be `(2016, 52)` and `(2020, 1)`.

I don't know how write a SQL statement that would give these two results.

I tried:

1.

```
SELECT date_part('year', date_trunc('week', TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00')); --2016 OK
SELECT date_part('week', date_trunc('week', TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00')); --52 OK
SELECT date_part('year', date_trunc('week', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00')); --2019 BUT I NEED 2020
SELECT date_part('week', date_trunc('week', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00')); --1 OK
```

2. 

```
SELECT date_part('year', TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00'); --2017 BUT I NEED 2016
SELECT date_part('week', TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00'); --52 OK
SELECT date_part('year', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00'); --2020 OK
SELECT date_part('week', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00'); --1 OK
```

Either way, there is always something wrong, and I would possibly like something that can give the correct results. My problem is that when I am grouping by year AND week, this way sometimes I am considering more than 7 days, and I would need to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `week` unit returns a week number based on the ISO standard. To get the equivalent year, use `isoyear`

```
SELECT date_part('isoyear', TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 
       date_part('week', TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
       date_part('isoyear', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00'), 
       date_part('week', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00');
```

returns:

```
date_part | date_part | date_part | date_part
----------+-----------+-----------+----------
     2016 |        52 |      2020 |         1
```

Comment: Great, 6 mins and I can accept your answer. Thank you very much;)